# I need a script that only redirect once per ip to the visitor

Tags: javascript, php

I just used code redirection by cookies but that's not what I need I want something that only redirects the visitor once per ip to avoid traffic hits

Comment: The question appears to include no attempt at all in trying to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first time, save the IP Address in Cookie and redirects the user. On the second time, just check the Current IP Address with save IP Address in cookie if that matches then do no redirect the user otherwise update the cookie and redirect the user again.

I think, this is the simple approach to get your work done.